Work Experience, No bachelor degree
I am an 18-year-old Java Developer with 1.5 years of professional experience. Currently, I am employed on a contract basis, with my contract being renewed annually due to my performance.
However, due to my workload, I have been unable to dedicate time to studying for a degree. I am concerned about how this may impact my future career prospects.
Is not having a degree likely to be a significant barrier in the long term, especially in the tech industry?

This is a matter of personal choice. No matter what we say, you know yourself and your details better, and only you can make the best decision. You need to decide your priorities, make a plan, and follow that plan.

Work experience >>>> degree

@TheDemonLord: In an engineering field, knowing that the candidate has been exposed to core algorithms and structures and practices matters a lot. A degree may not be necessary, but evidence of base knowledge is. Unfortunately our field doesn't yet have something standardized like the legal bar exam. Online certifications on lieu of academic classes may be sufficient. Industry would love not to have to pay college graduate salaries for this craft , but is still trying to figure out how to get there... and that isn't necessarily the way we coders want to see things go

If you want to be considered a professional, get your degree.  Once you get a full time job with decent benefits, work on a masters.  With the goal of having your company will pay for most if not all of your masters.  Without a degree you will be limiting yourself to employment opportunities and some of the best paying jobs.  For example you can count yourself out of most DOD contractor engineer positions.  In my opinion you are far better off "flipping burgers" at some mcjob so you can get your degree.

A lot of companies require degrees and will flat out reject you if you don't have one.
Some companies don't care, but they are in the minority. You need the degree to  get past HR's filter.

I feel like "Is not having a degree likely to be a significant barrier in the long term, especially in the tech industry?" Is a question that can be answered generally. And the answer would apply to a lot of people.

The times when you taught yourself software development are long over. It is a very specific job now, with specific requirements. Trial and error or a bunch of YouTube tutorials are not good enough.
Think of any other job. You can do a little bit of gardening or woodworking as a hobby. But if you employ someone as a professional, you expect more than that. And rightly so. The expectations of employers have risen over the last three decades. The workforce contains lots and lots of people with professional degrees now and that is the standard. That is what you are up against when you apply for a job.
On-the-job training can only teach you so much. It will always be specifics of a job. But there is so much more you don't know about and a professional education will teach you about all of it. It tries to prepare you to be a well rounded professional, not just a very experienced "unskilled laborer" in programming.
I cannot speak to the education system in your country. In my opinion a professional education does not necessarily mean college. In my country there are different paths available and different programs to get an education. Some are more abstract and theoretical like university, some are more hands on and practical, like apprenticeships. But all of them take 2-3 years. I guess that is the time it needs to absorb all the knowledge, regardless of the path you take. Don't be fooled by promises to make you a software developer in 6 weeks through some kind of bootcamp. They have their uses, but it is not a professional education, it does not play in the same league as a 2-3 year degree.
Look at the job ads in your country and region. What do they require? Are those hard requirements, or does it say "or comparable experience"? That is something only you can find out.
Think about it this way: in 20 years‘ time when you are forty...

Do you think there is a job that will reject you because you have no degree?
Do you think there will be a job that will reject you because you only have 19 years of experience instead of 22, because you "wasted" it on a degree?

I think the first option is waaaay more likely.

"The times when you taught yourself software development are long over." - I'm not sure that is true, though it's true (and always has been) that you don't teach yourself in a six-week bootcamp.
